# calculate and replace values inside span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site where I show the number of days the product is stored and a percentage of the total is charged based on the days. `data-ref` holds the percentage value to charge.

```js
var thistotal = $("#total").text();

var percent1 = $("#date-1").attr("data-ref");
var delrate1 = $("#date-rate-1").text();
var replace1_total = thistotal.replace("€", "").replace(",", ".").replace("+", "");
var percentVal = (percent1 / 100) * replace1_total;
$('#date-1').html(percentVal);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="radio">
  <label class="img2" style="">
    <span>
      <h3>Day</h3>
      1<br>
      <p>
        <span class="thedate" id="date-1" data-ref="20.00000000">$18.00</span>
        <span id="date-rate-1">+ $10.00</span>
      </p>
    </span>
  </label>
</li>
<ul class="thelist">
  <li class="radio">
    <label class="img2" style="">
      <span>
        <h3>Day</h3>
        3
        <br>
        <p>
          <span class="thedate" id="date-3" data-ref="25.00000000"></span>
          <span id="date-rate-3">+ $10.00</span>
        </p>
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="radio">
    <label class="img2" style="">
      <span>
        <h3>Day</h3>
        5<br>
        <p>
          <span class="thedate" id="date-5" data-ref="30.00000000"></span>
          <span id="date-rate-5">+ $10.00</span>
        </p>
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="total">$100.00</div>
```

To display the amount charged by day, I get the percentage value from the span's `data-ref` attribute, calculate the percentage from the total, and add it to the contents of that span.

I'm individually adding each `id` ("date-1", "date-2", etc.) to the span, performing the calculation, and its working fine. But the problem is there are many new options added, and some options are not added to certain products. So I have to duplicate the code to do each calculation (The numbers on the ids are the actual day values. Added them to make the ids unique).

What would be the be the best way to achieve this percentage calculation without duplicating the code?

Comment: What is `thistotal`? It's not set in your example code.

Comment: @terrymorse `thistotal` is the value from `<div id="total">$100.00</div>`

Comment: I added `thistotal` setting to the code and corrected the `$("#date-1")` line (was `#del-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly then you can use class selector, like this:

```
$('.thedate').each((index, item)=>{
  const dateRef = +($(item).attr("data-ref"))
  const dateRate = +($(item).next().html().replace("€", "").replace("$", "").replace(",", ".").replace("+", "").replace(" ", ""))
  $(item).parent().html((dateRef / 100) * dateRate)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the only problem is that the value is always added only to the first menu item. is it possible to show the values on each of those items?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is the intended process:

- get `total` from contents of `<div id="total">`
- get all spans with `class="thedate"`
- get `percent` from span's `data-ref` attribute
- update span's contents using a calculation(percent, total)

The following will produce the intended outcome for all spans with `class="thedate"`:

```js
function setTheDatePrices(total) {

  // get all spans with 'class="thedate"'
  let theDates = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('thedate'));

  // set the contents of each "thedate" span
  theDates.forEach(theDate => {
    let percent = Number(theDate.dataset.ref);
    theDate.innerHTML = '$' + (percent / 100 * total).toFixed(2);
  });
}

let run = () => {};

window.onload = () => {

  // obtain total from contents of  `<div id="total">`
  const total = Number(
    document.getElementById('total')
    .innerHTML.match(/[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/)
  );
  
  run = () => setTheDatePrices(total);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="run();">Set "thedate" Prices</button><br/>
<li class="radio">
  <label class="img2" style="">
    <span>
      <h3>Day</h3>
      1<br>
      <p>
        <span class="thedate" id="date-1" data-ref="20.00000000"></span>
        <span id="date-rate-1">+ $10.00</span>
      </p>
    </span>
  </label>
</li>
<ul class="thelist">
  <li class="radio">
    <label class="img2" style="">
      <span>
        <h3>Day</h3>
        3
        <br>
        <p>
          <span class="thedate" id="date-3" data-ref="25.00000000"></span>
          <span id="date-rate-3">+ $10.00</span>
        </p>
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="radio">
    <label class="img2" style="">
      <span>
        <h3>Day</h3>
        5<br>
        <p>
          <span class="thedate" id="date-5" data-ref="30.00000000"></span>
          <span id="date-rate-5">+ $10.00</span>
        </p>
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="total">$100.00</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that i want to add the calculated value to the relevant span tag..  fro an example `id="date-1" data-ref="20.00000000"` once i calculate the amount and then replace it with $18.. same way ` id="date-3" data-ref="25.00000000"` calculate the and then replace the value inside `<span class="thedate" id="date-5" data-ref="30.00000000">CALCULATED VALUE</span>`  so on.

Comment: @LiveEn See my revised answer, simplified after learning what you intended.